# Get records modified within the last year from current date

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have a result set which has structure as follows.

```
List<BudgtedData> budgetData;
public class BudgtedData
{
    public decimal BudgetedCpmDataId { get; set; }
    public int ForecastYear { get; set; }
    public int ForecastMonth { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the records within the last year. For example If I run the code in 2015 March it should return 2014 March to 2015 Feb
.How I can achieve this in linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code should work for you:

```
int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year; int currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;

var result = budgetData.Where(
       b => (b.ForecastYea.Equals(currentYear - 1)  
             && b.ForecastMonth >= currentMonth )
             ||(b.ForecastYear.Equals(currentYear)                       
             && b.ForecastMonth <= currentMonth - 1))
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Its return only within the year 2014. If I run the code in 2015 March it should return 2014 March to 2015 Feb

Comment: @udaya726 now I understand you, I will change answer to suit this situation in a minute

Comment: this qurery is equal to the following    select*
 from 
[kpi].[BudgetedCpmData]
where [ForecastYear]<=2015 AND [ForecastYear]>=2014 AND [ForecastMonth]<=1 AND [ForecastMonth]>=2

Comment: @udaya726 I am sorry, you are correct. Please test edited answer again

Comment: @Adil Mammadov may be we both came to same solution ;)

Comment: @KcDoD yes, they are same indeed ))

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :

```
var res = budgetData.Where(r => ((r.ForecastYear == (DateTime.Today.Year - 1) && r.ForecastMonth >= DateTime.Today.Month) || (r.ForecastYear == DateTime.Today.Year && r.ForecastMonth < DateTime.Today.Month))).ToList();
```

Explanation : If the year is one year back [for 2015 it's 2014] select data from Current month onward. Else if the year is current year, select data from months prior to this month.

A working Example :

```
 List<BudgtedData> budgetData = new List<BudgtedData>();
 budgetData.Add(new BudgtedData() { BudgetedCpmDataId = 1, ForecastMonth = 12, ForecastYear = 2014 });
 budgetData.Add(new BudgtedData() { BudgetedCpmDataId = 1, ForecastMonth = 1, ForecastYear = 2014 });
 budgetData.Add(new BudgtedData() { BudgetedCpmDataId = 1, ForecastMonth = 1, ForecastYear = 2013 });
 budgetData.Add(new BudgtedData() { BudgetedCpmDataId = 2, ForecastMonth = 2, ForecastYear = 2014 });
 budgetData.Add(new BudgtedData() { BudgetedCpmDataId = 2, ForecastMonth = 1, ForecastYear = 2015 });


 var res = budgetData.Where(r => ((r.ForecastYear == (DateTime.Today.Year - 1) && r.ForecastMonth >= DateTime.Today.Month) || (r.ForecastYear == DateTime.Today.Year && r.ForecastMonth < DateTime.Today.Month))).ToList();

 foreach (BudgtedData item in res)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(item.ForecastYear + "  "+ item.ForecastMonth);
 }
```

Output :

```
 2014 12
 2014 2
 2015 1
```